# Error trying to loop through array of hashes in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, flow-control

This has been asked before a couple of times, but none of those answers seem to work for my situation.

My code:

```
open(FILE, "<", $fileb) or die "File not openable: $!";
while (<FILE>) {
    $filebmeta[$line] = (data => $_, match => -1);
    $line++;
}
close(FILE);
$line = 0;


for my $hashref (@filebmeta) {
     print "$hashref->{data}\n";
}
```

when I run this code it spits out: 'Can't use string ("-1") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at ./partc.pl line 152.'

Any idea why this is happening?  I don't seem to be able to dereference the hash properly in the loop.

Comment: Instead of `$line` use `$.`. Also, `use warnings` will solve this.

Comment: Or use `push` instead of assigning to a numbered array element with `$line` or `$.`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The elements of the array need to be hashrefs, so your assigment statement needs to use curly brackets:

```
$filebmeta[$line] = {data => $_, match => -1};
```

You code is assigning a list to the array, so it just gets the last element in the list which is the `-1`. Thus your error message.

Answer (score 4):

Your expression `(data => $_, match => -1)` does not create a hashref, it creates a list.  You probably meant `{data => $_, match => -1}`

Answer (score -1):

You mean besides all the undefined variables in your code?  Read perlreftut and pay attention to the syntax.

Comment: They're all declared, just out of the scope of my code snipit.